# Is there a word to describe answers that are completely correct but entirely useless under the circumstances?

Tags: single-word-requests

[Irregular Webcomic No. 1785](https://irregularwebcomic.net/1785.html) says:

> Monty: Dad, is there a word to describe answers that are completely correct but entirely useless under the circumstances?
>
> Prof. Jones: Yes, yes there is.

Is that really such a word?

Comment: It's just a joke, of course, so I'm not sure that such a word exists. The closest that I can think of is "trivial" (or its synonyms).

Comment: Voting to reopen, since the proposed dupe isn't really the same as this question.

Comment: Non-sequitur?..

Answer (score 0):

*Moot* is an interesting word here. However, I know of no word that combines the concepts of correct and irrelevant.  I think of a moot question as one for which the the answer, right or wrong, is irrelevant.

The AHD provides this https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=mootusage note on *moot:*

> Usage Note: The adjective moot is originally a legal term going back to the 1500s. It derives from the noun moot in its sense of a hypothetical case argued as an exercise by law students. The noun moot in turn goes back to an Old English word meaning "a meeting, especially one convened for legislative or judicial purposes." Consequently, a moot question is one that is arguable or open to debate. But in the mid-1800s, people also began to look at the hypothetical side of moot as its essential meaning, and they started to use the word to mean "of no significance or relevance." Thus a moot point, however debatable, is one that has no practical value. A number of critics have objected to this usage, but in our 2008 survey 83 percent of the Usage Panel accepted it in the sentence The nominee himself chastised the White House for failing to do more to support him, but his concerns became moot when a number of Republicans announced that they, too, would oppose the nomination. This represents a significant increase over the 59 percent that accepted the same sentence in 1988. Writers who use this word should be sure that the context makes clear which sense of moot is meant. It is often easier to use another word, such as debatable or irrelevant.